# Laravel: Undefined property when accessing parent from child through a Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have three models: **Store**, **Lab** and **Inventory**. Inventory can belong to either one via a polymorphic relationship.

```
class Store extends Model
{
    public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(\App\Models\Inventory::class, 'keeper');
    }
}


class Lab extends Model
{
    public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(\App\Models\Inventory::class, 'keeper');
    }
}


class Inventory extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['keeper'];

    public function keeper()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function getKeeperAttribute()
    {
        return $this->keeper;
    }
}
```

When I try to access the parent from an Inventory instance using the "keeper" property I get this

```
Undefined property: App\\Models\\Inventory::$keeper
```

I have `keeper_id` and `keeper_type` on my `inventories` table and data is inserting just fine with the relationships attached.

```
Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('keeper_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('keeper_type')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
});
```

`dd($this->keeper());` returns the relationship correctly:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo {#1326 ▼
  #morphType: "keeper_type"
  #models: null
  #dictionary: []
  #macroBuffer: []
  #morphableEagerLoads: []
  #morphableEagerLoadCounts: []
  #morphableConstraints: []
  #child: App\Models\Inventory {#1302 ▶}
  #foreignKey: "keeper_id"
  #ownerKey: "id"
  #relationName: "keeper"
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1321 ▶}
  #parent: App\Models\Inventory {#1302 ▶}
  #related: App\Models\Store {#1305 ▶}
  #withDefault: null
}
```

So why isn't `$this->keeper;` working? What could be the problem?

Comment: try by changing either relationship name or property name from `keeper` to something else

Comment: Yes, That seemed to be the problem. I had to use a different property name for it to work. Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to make an accessor for a relationship, if you just make sure it is loaded it will be in the serialized output